# php simple html dom script does not accept own website

Tags: php, html, dom, web

With the following script: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

The code to include my own page gives the following error:

> [Tue Dec 30 21:54:47 2014] [error] [client 84.241.198.67] FastCGI: server "/var/run/php-fpm/php54/php-cgi" stderr:  in xxxx/simple_html_dom.php on line 75
>   [Tue Dec 30 21:54:47 2014] [error] [client 84.241.198.67] FastCGI: server "/var/run/php-fpm/php54/php-cgi" stderr: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in xxxxx/www/design/header.php on line 46

This is the code I use. (When I use 'http://www.google.com' for example it does work. But with my own URL it keeps giving errors (not loading the page)

```
$html = file_get_html('website/verslagdetail/2');

// find all link
foreach($html->find('h3') as $e) 
echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
```

What can be the problem? I want to use this to create a nice  for each page and let this code decide the title

Comment: What error? Please provide more details about the problem.

Comment: Please also show what do you as parameter?( You can use pseudo names, but something like: `http://mysite.ch/xy/`)

Comment: When I put my own website url in the $html variable the website does not work. When I put Google there it does work and gets attributes from there. I posted the lines from the errorlog above. Why it does that is a clue for me

Comment: I tried using the full url like strongbase.nl/verslagdetail/2 and I tried full url like StrongBase.nl/verslag.php?id=2

Comment: The URL you are providing throws 500 Internal Server Error.
You have to fix that page first.

Comment: The url works but it does Not work now because I have the error in header.php

Comment: You are trying to fetch a page in the header.php file, but the page you are trying to fetch also includes the header.php file. You must change this approach.

Comment: Mm okay that seems logic. Im on my phone right now and gonna continue tommorow morning.

Comment: Gotta think good about this. Because i need to define the title between the <h> tags of most of the pages to use in the headers titles. And in the meta tags in the head to complete the info for Facebook share button

Answer (score 0):

It just looks like this is a path issue. `$html` is non reference likely meaning that file_get_html() on the path "website/verslagdetail/2" didn't resolve to anything. You most likely need to fix that relative path or use an absolute path

Comment: I understand. But in the case Google.com works, why doesnt my full website url doesnt work then?